# Item name/description with CI Merchant

Tags: php, codeigniter, ci-merchant

I've been playing with CI Merchant library and have a question about the item name/description when I get to the PayPal checkout page. Basically this is what I get when I send my request.

[image]

My question now is, how do I change the name and description of an item to something like "banner size XXX"? I tried adding **L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NAMEm** and **L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_DESCm** but then it just keeps on doing nothing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, what I needed to pass is the **PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC** and not the single items! All done :).

Comment: I think you can also just pass `description` through in your `$params` array

Comment: Yes it seems I can! But I added some fields to my paypal express class.
`$request[$prefix.'DESC'] = $this->param('description');
    $request['L_'.$prefix.'DESC0'] = 'Website banner: '.$this->param('description');
    $request['L_'.$prefix.'AMT0'] = $this->param('amount');
    $request['L_'.$prefix.'NAME0'] = $this->param('description');`

But I still have a problem in Transaction Details, it says in order - Order Description: 0, but I guess that's not too much of a hassle :).

Comment: Forgot to mention that `$prefix` is `$prefix = 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_';`

Answer (score 0):

Please add `name` and `description` parameters in `purchase_return` method which you will be calling after payment `complete`.